# Proof of Stirling Number Identity Using Recursive Definition

Tags: combinatorics

Let the 2nd kind Stirling numbers be defined by $S(n, 0)=S(0, n)=\delta_{0, n}$ and $S(n, k)=S(n, k-1)+kS(n-1, k-1)$. I would like to prove the identity $x^n=\sum_k S(n, k)(x)_k$ using the recursive definition directly. I know the proof that writes the set of functions from $n\to x$ as the union over $k$ of surjective functions onto a subset of $x$ of size $k$, but I'd like a proof that uses the recursive definition directly.

Comment: what is $(x)_k$?

Comment: @ModdedBear $(x)_k = x(x-1)\cdots(x-k+1)$, Feller's notation I think.

Comment: @ModdedBear: Pochhammer symbol for falling factorial; I prefer $x^{\underline k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll use the notation that I prefer; ${n\brace k}=S(n,k)$, and $x^{\underline k}=(x)_k$.

Use the fact that $x^{\underline{k+1}}=x^{\underline k}(x-k)=x\cdot x^{\underline k}-kx^{\underline k}$, so that $x\cdot x^{\underline k}=x^{\underline{k+1}}+kx^{\underline k}$:

$$\begin{align*}
x^n&=x\cdot x^{n-1}\\
&=x\sum_k{{n-1}\brace k}x^{\underline k}\\
&=\sum_k{{n-1}\brace k}x^{\underline{k+1}}+\sum_k{{n-1}\brace k}kx^{\underline k}\\
&=\sum_k{{n-1}\brace{k-1}}x^{\underline k}+\sum{{n-1}\brace k}kx^{\underline k}\\
&=\sum_k\left({{n-1}\brace{n-1}}+k{{n-1}\brace k}\right)x^{\underline k}\\
&=\sum_k{n\brace k}x^{\underline k}\;.
\end{align*}$$

This argument is straight out of Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*.